# SMTP server does not respond to `SmtpClient` connection attempt. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

I tried to write code for sending an email with .NET. This is what I have so far:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("mymailaddress@yahoo.com", address);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
client.Port = 587;
client.Send(e);
```

The problem is I get the following exception:

> *Unhandled Exception: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException`: Failure sending mail.*
>
> > *`System.Net.WebException`: Unable to connect to the remote server.*
> >
> > > *`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
> > >       did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond `173.194.66.109:587`*

Comment: I think you need client.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: have you done setting in your Appconfig??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;  

// ...

MailAddress maFrom = new MailAddress("<address>", "<display_name>");
MailAddress maTo = new MailAddress("<address>", "<display_name>");
const string sPassword = "<password>";
const string sSubject = "<subject>";
const string sBody = "<body>";

new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(maFrom.Address, sPassword)
}.Send(new MailMessage(maFrom, maTo) { Subject = sSubject, Body = sBody });
```